# How can I modify/overwrite a role variable inside the role in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm writing a role, to which the user can pass a list. Inside that role, I want to add items to this list conditionally, before processing it in my role. The role variable is called `my_list`. It  is passed to the role like this:

```yaml
---
- name: Do something
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - role: my.role
      my_list:
        - { name: test1, url: 'http://foo.bar' }
        - { name: test2, url: 'http://foo.bar' }
```

Inside my role, I try to modify the role variable like this:

```yaml
---
- name: Do something
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    my_list: "{{ my_list + internal_list }}"
  when: condition_is_met

- debug:
    var: my_list
```

But it does not work; the list does not get modified. If I use a new variable name, it works:

```yaml
---
- name: Do something
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    my_new_list: "{{ my_list + internal_list }}"
  when: condition_is_met

- debug:
    var: my_new_list
```

So I think it is related to variable scopes. `set_fact` will set a host variable, which has a lower priority than the role variable. If `set_fact` is not suitable to modify role variables, how can it be done then?

Comment: See [Ansible variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

Comment: I see. Putting variables in place of [keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#role) is not a syntax error.

Comment: For the record. See [Role argument evaluation and validation behaving inconsistently #75098](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/75098).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_fact` will overwrite a role variable if it actually is a role variable and not a role parameter. Excerpt from [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence):

> 15. role vars (defined in role/vars/main.yml)
> 16. block vars (only for tasks in block)
> 17. task vars (only for the task)
> 18. include_vars
> 19. set_facts / registered vars
> 20. role (and include_role) params

With:

```yaml
---
- name: Do something
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - role: my.role
      my_list:
        - { name: test1, url: 'http://foo.bar' }
        - { name: test2, url: 'http://foo.bar' }
```

I was passing `my_list` as a role parameter. If I pass it as a role variable, `set_fact` works:

```yaml
---
- name: Do something
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - role: my.role
      vars:
        my_list:
          - { name: test1, url: 'http://foo.bar' }
          - { name: test2, url: 'http://foo.bar' }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this if `internal_list` is string

```yaml
- name: Do something
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    my_list: "{{ my_list + [ internal_list ] }}"
  when: condition_is_met
```

Try this if `internal_list` is list

```yaml
- name: Do something
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    my_list: "{{ my_list + [ item ] }}"
  loop: internal_list
  when: condition_is_met
```

Comment: That does not make a difference.

Comment: `internal_list` is the value or variable ?

Comment: It is a variable, that contains a list.

Comment: ok, got it.. `my_list: "{{ my_list + [ internal_list ] }}"` is appending a list. it works only if `internal_list` is an item(string). In your case, you are merging 2 list variables so, it is working only with new variable `my_new_list: "{{ my_list + internal_list }}"`